# How does Anonymonkey work?

Tags: anonymous

After 10 hours googling.
I can't find any clue about the principle of work of it.
There is no wiki of it, almost no one talk about it.
The company is a mysterious.
The only thing I know is its website,
https://anonymonkey.com/

There is nothing on the website but only teach you how to use it.
It has been used in many Facebook page, like "Crushes and Confessions" page.
But no one talk about how it works.

Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AnonyMonkey was started by someone named Zihan Xu at the University of Chicago: http://blog.entrepreneurship.uchicago.edu/post/93970327565/accelerator-spotlight-on-anonymonkey

Basically, the "company" you refer to is a startup (with no apparent business model). There were some serious security concerns with AnonyMonkey - for example, submissions are not actually anonymous as they require people to log in to Facebook to do so: http://chicagomaroon.com/2015/04/07/anonymity-not-guaranteed-on-uchicago-crushes-and-secrets/

If you're looking to make a Facebook confessions page, I suggest something that's truly anonymous such as CrushNinja.